# Is this past tense or has this changed to present tense?

Tags: tenses, past-tense

I'm sorta new to writing and I'm wondering is this past tense or has this changed to present tense?

"The hum of the bike quickly filled the air as Eddie **finished drinking** his water."

Comment: *Finished* is past tense. *Drinking* has no tense at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand this sentence, the word "as" is the key.  It is a conjunction which is connecting two independent clauses: "The hum of the bike quickly filled the air" and "Eddie finished drinking his water."  The word "as" also implies that the two clauses it connects happen at the same time, so you can expect "finished" to be the same tense as "filled".

Comment: So what your saying is that its past tense, right? Sorry I'm not that savvy at grammar.

Comment: Yes!  I should have put that in the reply.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help!